# Is there a simple way to do it with lambdas?

Tags: java, lambda

I just need to compare answers from givenAnswers with correctAnswers from each question from questions and then return list of failedQuestions.
I wonder how could I do same things with lamdas.

```
private List<Question> checkAnswer(List<Answer> givenAnswers, List<Question> questions){
    List<Question> failedQuestions = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=0; i<givenAnswers.size(); i++){
        if(!givenAnswers.get(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(questions.get(i)
                                                    .getCorrectAnswer().toString()))
            failedQuestions.add(questions.get(i));
    }

    return failedQuestions;
}
```

Here is the code of Answer class:

```
public class Answer {
private final String content;

public Answer(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return content;
}
```

}

and the Question class:

```
public class Question {
private final int id;
private final String content;
private final List<Answer> answerList;
private final Answer correctAnswer;

public Question(int id, String content, List<Answer> answerList, Answer correctAnswer) {
    this.id = id;
    this.content = content;
    this.answerList = answerList;
    this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public List<Answer> getAnswerList() {
    return answerList;
}

public Answer getCorrectAnswer(){
    return correctAnswer;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder answersInLine = new StringBuilder();

    for (Answer answer : answerList) {
        answersInLine.append(answer.toString()).append('\t');
    }

    return "Question " + id +
            ":\n" + content +
            '\n' + answersInLine.toString() + '\n';
}
```

}

Is there any simple solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two array,maybe lambdas is not suitable.

```
private List<Question> checkAnswer2(List<Answer> a, List<Question> q){
    AtomicInteger ato = new AtomicInteger(0);
    return q.stream().filter(e->{
        int i = ato.getAndIncrement();
        return a.get(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(q.get(i).getCorrectAnswer().toString());
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Even your example is complicated, I cannot think of an easier solution. So, probably lambdas are not an option in this case.